# Disable volume up/down to open camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an app using firebase scanning to scan barcodes. I want to disable the use of volume up/down to open the scanner/camera. I also want the user to be able to still change the volume using those button.

I tried overwriting the onKeyDown event on my base activity but it doesn't fix my issue.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try returning true, not false.  False means you didn't handle it, so it may be passed to other handlers.  True means its handled.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I didn't try that before posting here